# gazebo without ros + urdf file

Tags: gazebo

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Hello,

1. I would like to know if it is possible to control a robot (applying force on joints with a c++ algorithm) in gazebo without ros to make a lot a simulations. In order to try evolutionary or reinforcement learning algorithms (could requires 500 000 simulations for instance).
   Usually, I use only a low level physic engine like ODE in C++ to skip any unnecessary computations.
2. I have access to an [URDF model](https://github.com/poppy-project/poppy-humanoid/tree/master/hardware/URDF). Is it possible to import it in gazebo without ROS ?

It is not clear to me how to apply force/torque on a robot. I saw that I can use Player or ROS in tutorials. However I also saw that there is an external API on physics engines.

What would be the fastest/lightweight method?

Thank you.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/9266/gazebo-without-ros-+-urdf-file/) by [matthieu637](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/1348/matthieu637/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 3 on 2015-09-04

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Hi,

you can just load an urdf as normal model. You just have to load an URDF instead of SDF. But loading URDFs can be tricky from time to time so you should use an SDF when you can.

Here is an example model.config:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<model>
  <name>YOUR_MODEL</name>
  <version>1.0</version>
  <sdf>YOUR_MODEL.urdf</sdf>
  <author>
    <name>Your Name</name>
    <email>your@mail.com</email>
  </author>
  
  <description>
    Small description of the model 
  </description>
</model>
```

Have a look at this tutorial series if you do not know how to set up a robot

http://gazebosim.org/tutorials?cat=build_robot

for your first question a model plugin is the right way to go...

---

Originally posted by [evilBiber](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/251/evilbiber/) with karma: 881 on 2015-09-07

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0